# Adding items to a list with for loop in Python

Tags: python

My code compare actual file type to extension and return a result. I had to adjust it to return the results and reuse other function but I'm stuck and I don't know why my script appends only one item to a list and generates no error whatsoever. I would get a result like `['asd', 'fgh', etc..]`.  What I'm doing wrong?

```
import os, sys

sys.argv.append("C:/temp/ver_files/")
dirct = set(os.listdir(sys.argv[1]))

file_sigs = {
    b'\xff\xd8\xff': (
        '.jpg',
        '.jpeg',
        '.JPG',
        '.JPEG'
    ),
    b'\x47\x49\x46': (
        '.gif',
        '.GIF'
    ),
    b'\x89\x50\x4e': (
        '.png',
        '.PNG'
    ),
    b'\x50\x4b\x03': (
        '.docx',
        '.DOCX'
    ),
    b'\x42\x4d': (
        '.bmp',
        '.BMP'
    )
}

for i in dirct:
    inf = []
    file = open(sys.argv[1]+i, "rb")
    sig = file.read(3)
    file.close()
    ext = os.path.splitext(i)[1]
    if len(inf) >= 0:
        if sig in file_sigs.keys():
            if ext in file_sigs[sig]:
                inf.append('Matching extension: '+ ext+ ' for file: '+i)
            else:
                inf.append('No matching extension for file: '+i+" it's a "+ file_sigs[sig][0]+ ' file')
        else:
            inf.append('No such signature in database')

print(inf)
```

Comment: Its because you are creating a brand new list each time you loop.

Comment: Sorry for bother, now I see it...

Comment: What's the point of `if len(inf) >= 0`? When would that not be true?

Comment: it's remainder from my other tests, deleted

Comment: Probably you will get `'No such signature in database'` a lot of times. ...
You are reading just 3 bytes